# Does the sequence of indexed values matter in a relational database?

Tags: postgresql, relational-database, database-performance

Let's say I have a table with a primary key 'ID' (integer).

If I populate 100.000.000 records where all the IDs are sequenced: (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, ...).
So the minimum ID is 1 and maximum is 100.000.000.

Will a query be faster then if the IDs where scattered: (3, 89, 100, 101, 232, 767, ...).

Can a database like PostgreSQL or Oracle use this to somehow increase the performance of the search (even though the comparison is just 'bigger then', 'lesser then' (I suppose)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That make not difference. because usually the index create a tree structure to store the values, so the search take `Log(n)` *(n number of items)* to find the item.

Also is almost imposible keep the items in sequence if you allow insert/delete. Unless you pay a big cost on updating.

[image]